# ffmpeg - How to render subtitle at a specific time as an image

Tags: ffmpeg, images

I wanted to render an image with the subtitle filter. I wanted an image that supports transparency so I am planning to render it as a bitmap. I also need to specify the time of the subtitle. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmaps do not support transparency; you want an output format like PNG instead.

ffmpeg [since Aug 30, 2017](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=f19e4118e9ca392f89d3c264aa8490b7d9ac3284)  has an `alpha` option for the [`subtitles` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1) which enables you to draw subtitles on transparent background. You have to generate this transparent background using the `color` filter.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:12 -f lavfi -i "color=color=white@0.0:size=200x200,format=rgba,subtitles=subs.srt:alpha=1" -frames:v 1 out.png
```

Note:

- Your subtitles must be in the file `subs.srt`
- You can specify the time of the subtitles with the `-ss` option (e.g., `03:12` here)
- The size of the video is set as an option of the `color` filter – it's 200⨉200 here

Comment: Is this feature included in any of the release builds? If it is, which version?

Comment: In none of the latest releases, but any commit from `f19e41` onwards – best to download a static build: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html